# Combination of Keypresses using JS / jQuery ( Escape & Shift +Escape )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way in js/jQuery how to have these two combinations of keypresses?

<kbd>ESCape</kbd> key
and
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESCape</kbd> key

when I implemented it using:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){if (e == null) {keycode = event.keyCode;}
else         {keycode = e.which;}
if(keycode == 27){closeAll();}}

//upon pressing shift + esc
$(document).bind('keypress',function(event)
{
      if(event.which === 27 && event.shiftKey)
    {
  closetogether();
   }

});
```

The <kbd>escape</kbd> button works perfectly but the one with the <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd> is getting confused I think because it's doing nothing. Don't worry the function works as when I change the combining key 27 to 90 (<kbd>z</kbd>) for example it works just fine.

Can someone opt me for a better way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you bind the `keydown` event using jQuery? That way you would already have a normalized event variable. You can also check the status of the shift key in the same handler.

These events send different keycodes back. Use `keyup/keydown` for capturing certain keys by scancodes and use `keypress` to capture actual text input by characters.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.which === 27){
        if(event.shiftKey){
            closetogether();
        } else {
            closeAll();
        }
    }
});
```